# How to store brush stroke information

Tags: database-design, data-structures, html5-canvas

I'm going to develop a demo application that stimulates MS Paint but runs on the web (HTML5). Currently I've implemented the brush feature (exactly like MS Paint) but I want to store each brush stroke in the database. Yet I havn't found out a data structure to store a brush stroke. Do you guys think that an array of consecutive point (x,y) can hold a brush stroke info?

```
class point
{
    float x, y;
}

class brush 
{
   List<point> data;
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: [tag:database-design] and [tag:data-structures] why?

Comment: I think data-structures is a more proper tag than database-design. Sorry if I overused the tag

Answer (score 0):

Yes, saving points is a good way to do it.

Remember that your first point on each line is a context.moveTo. Then you can easily replay the remaining strokes using context.lineTo.

I assume you need colors and width info on each brush stroke too.

Here's a starting schema:

```
table: Points
pointId int [primary key]
strokeID int, [key to table Strokes]
pointX int,
pointY int

table: Strokes
strokeId int, [primary key]
fillStyle varchar,
strokeStyle varchar,
lineWidth int
```